# NetSuite Javascript Error: org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@26e0a9d9

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

```
 function updatetaxcode()
{
var record = nlapiGetNewRecord();
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','id', record);

var tranType = record.getRecordType();
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','type', tranType);

var loc = "2315"


var numLines = nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG','count', numLines);

for (var i=1; i<= numLines; i++)
{
var lineLoc = nlapiGetLineItemValue('item', 'taxcode', i);

 nlapiSetLineItemValue('item', 'taxcode', i, loc);
  }
   }
```

The script is setting the value on **taxcode** field and working fine. When I see under workflow logs, I see the error :

> "Script result value:  org.mozilla.javascript.Undefined@26e0a9d9".

This is a custom workflow action script.

Answer (score 0):

NetSuite expects custom workflow actions to return something.  Since you script does not return anything, thats what you get when you look at workflow logs.